# Strong approximation of operators.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

If I want to approximate strongly an operator $T$ with another in a subset $A \in L(H)$
why is not enough to ask "for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an operator $S\in A$  such that for every $\eta \in H$  $\|T\eta - S\eta\|<\epsilon$" but it's necessary to ask that:

"for every $\epsilon>0$ and every choice of n vectors $\eta_1,..,\eta_n \in H$ there is an operator $S\in A$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n\|T\eta_i - S\eta_i\|^2<\epsilon^2$"?

Comment: $L(H)$ stands here for linear span of $H$?

Comment: No, it stands for the bounded linear operators from $H$ to itself

Comment: In the strong operator topology a sequence of operators $(S_n)$ converges to $T$ iff $\|S_nx-Tx\|\xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{} 0$ for all $x\in H$.

Comment: From Averson's "Invitation to c*-algebras" proving the double commutant theorem: "It suffices to show that each operator $T \in A''$ can be strongly approximated by operators in $A$; that is, for every $\epsilon > 0$ and every choice of n vectors $\eta_1,..,\eta_n \in H$ there is an operator $S\in A$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n\|T\eta_i - S\eta_i\|^2<\epsilon^2$" To conclude the theorem he proves it for $n=1$ and he finishes proving the general case for $n=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, It's because asking that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an operator $S\in A$  such that for every $\eta \in H$  $\|T\eta - S\eta\|<\epsilon$ is equivalent to ask that for every $\epsilon>0$ and every choice of n vectors $\eta_1,..,\eta_n \in H$ there is an operator $S\in A$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n\|T\eta_i - S\eta_i\|^2<\epsilon^2$ (notice the order of the statements: in the first the operator $S$ approximates $T\eta$ for every $\eta$, in the second you first choose the n vector an then you find an appropriate $S$ for those vectors.

The equivalence of the two request is obtained with a little difficulty but after a bit of thinking is intuitively true.